# Weird setcookie behavior

Tags: php, ajax, setcookie

I'll try to explain it as best as I can.
I'm trying to solve this issue for days, and I just don't know what is wrong.

First of all, I'm opening an simple 'dialog' that I made by an function.
Let's call it `openDialog` for now.
In my sub-domain, I'm opening the register dialog with this function,
and the function does, is using ajax to read the register dialog content.
And with that, I can simply register without any issue .

The register is working on my main server (example.com), and the forum's sub domain. (forum.example.com)

The login works the same. I got query in the ajax and other stuff.
Here is the problem: in the main site (example.com) the login is setting up the cookie.
However, in the sub-domain (forum.example.com) the ajax does the same query to the mysql (last login date and etc..),
but the setcookie isn't working.

I'm using chrome, and I saw that in the Network tab (Developer mode) I do see that the ajax response created the cookie, but the cookie isn't really created.

Here is the setcookie:

```
setcookie("mycoockiename", 'myvalue', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/', '.example.com');
```

When I go to the chrome developer mode (pressing on F12) then to the Network tab > the ajax request and in the Headers tab I can see:

```
Set-Cookie:mycoockiename=myvalue; expires=Sun, 18-Jan-2015 21:05:20 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com
```

Great, so that means that I've successfully created the cookie right ?
Well, no. It doesn't really create it.

And it is important that you guys know that. Its only happened in the sub-domain (forum.exapmle.com) in the (example.com) everything working perfectly.
In the (forum.example.com) everything working except the setcookie.

Also note that, while I'm creating this cookie via the main site (example.com), I can also see this cookie in the (forum.example.com)

So, any idea about why ?

Comment: How do you know it is not working?

Comment: Chrome let you see the cookies in the current page, and that cookie isn't there. also I'm using this cookie to check if the user is logged in. in the main site (example.com) I can see the cookie and also I can see that the user is logged in. and in the (forum.example.com) I don't see it.

Comment: What are you using at backend?

Comment: java, php? and where do you set cookie?

Comment: I set the cookie with php ..

Comment: Is it possible to share firebug network headers section of domain and subdomain? I can comment further. Also be sure that your protocol is http on all domains

Comment: To mean to this one .. ? http://gyazo.com/6489ff36195624cb8e03e8a50fca55fc.png

Comment: Yes, and there is no section "Cookie" on Request Headers part. I working exapmle, you will see that there is a "Cookie" key on Request Header part.

Comment: I do see the cookie there .. but its not really saving it. (under Response Cookies, the Request Cookies is empty.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I just created that missing cookie with javascript.